# What is a good way to code Java for multiple versions of Hadoop?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, protocol-buffers, dry

I am writing Java code toward multiple Hadoop clusters, one of which is HDP 2.2 and another CDH4. I write code that needs to be runnable on both. This results in requiring different versions of multiple Hadoop dependencies, which are not backward compatible. For example, the HDP version requires use of Protobuf for Hbase for custom Filters, because it's newer than 0.96, whereas CDH4 uses Hbase 0.94. I have reduced all Hadoop dependencies for my code down to a few packages in one API, and have used Maven Profiles for code that depends on that, but I'd like to utilize the DRY principle if possible so that code that I write to develop toward that API doesn't have to be cherry-picked or copied from HDP to CDH4 each time I make a change.

I currently have this code in multiple git branches, but that has been hard to maintain.

I realize that Java is intended for write once, run anywhere, but this is one of those cases where it doesn't seem to work out easily.  I can think of a few potential options, some of which would potentially refactor only the code that can't be repeated into a separate location:

- Use Maven submodules and select a submodule based on the Hadoop version I'm building towards with Maven Profiles.
- Refactor the code from multiple git branches into separate Java packages in the same project, and use Maven Profiles and the Maven compiler exclude option to select the package based on the Hadoop version.
- There are probably better solutions that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would organize the project into at least 3 submodules, e.g.

- project

  - common
  - v2stuff
  - v4stuff

Depending on how you deliver your project, you may have a couple more submodules which assemble the final artifacts for each version of hadoop.